# Node js,Sequelize findAndCountAll with offset and limit doesn't work when contains "include" and "where: array[]" options

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to fetch paginated messages from a database given the ids of different chats. It works if I do not provide limit and offset, but when I provide the limit and offset parameters, it stops working. I use mariadb sql.

```
Message.findAndCountAll({
            where: {chat_id: ids},//ids=> array of ints
            offset: limit * page,
            limit: limit,
            include: {
                model: UnreadMessage, as: 'unreadMessages',
                where: {participant_id: userId}
            }
        },
    )
```

The error I see is this

```
"(conn=12896, no: 1064, SQLState: 42000) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''20') AS `messages` INNER JOIN `unread_message` AS `unreadMessages` ON `messa...' at line 1\nsql: SELECT `messages`.*, `unreadMessages`.`message_id` AS `unreadMessages.message_id`, `unreadMessages`.`participant_id` AS `unreadMessages.participant_id` FROM (SELECT `messages`.`id`, `messages`.`chat_id`, `messages`.`content`, `messages`.`sender_id`, `messages`.`created_at` FROM `messages` AS `messages` WHERE `messages`.`chat_id` IN (3, 5) AND ( SELECT `message_id` FROM `unread_message` AS `unreadMessages` WHERE (`unreadMessages`.`participant_id` = 10 AND `unreadMessages`.`message_id` = `messages`.`id`) LIMIT 1 ) IS NOT NULL LIMIT 0, '20') AS `messages` INNER JOIN `unread_message` AS `unreadMessages` ON `messages`.`id` = `unreadMessages`.`message_id` AND `unreadMessages`.`participant_id` = 10; - parameters:[]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My speculation was right all along when I first saw it. The error says it all.

```
...right syntax to use near ''20') AS `mess....
```

`limit` is string. Cast it using `+limit`.
If I'm right, you're passing it from the request directly without casting it to `integer`.

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer IF IT IS. That helps me gain reputation so I can comment everywhere. It's frustrating. Really.

Comment: Parsing string to int using ``parseInt()`` fixed the issue. Thanks @mdy-nnl